# Smooth maps between manifolds and continuity hypothesis

Tags: analysis, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

According to Loring Tu's book:

> Let $N$ and $M$ be manifolds of dimension $n$ and $m$, respectively. A map $F: N \to M$ is $C^{\infty}$ at a point $p \in N$ if there is a chart $(V,\psi)$ in $M$ containing $F(p)$ and a chart $(U,\phi)$ in $N$ containing $p$ such that the composition $\psi \circ F\circ \phi^{-1}$, a map from an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, is $C^{\infty}$ at $\phi(p)$. By the continuity of $F$, one can always choose $U$ small enough so that $F(U) \subset V$.

My question is straightforward. The map $F$ in the above definition is just a map between (smooth) manifolds. This does not seem to imply *continuous*. However, the last sentence of the definition assumes $F$ is continuous. I did not find any mention in the book that a "map" means "continuous map" or something like this, and I don't think being a map between smooth manifolds implies continuity. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a chart $(V, \psi)$, I assume the definition is $\psi \colon V \to \psi(V) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism.

If $\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}$ is a smooth map between open subsets of Euclidean space, then it is also continuous. Then $$F = \psi^{-1} \circ (\psi \circ F \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ \phi$$ in a neighborhood of $p$ and is a composition of continuous maps, hence it is continuous at $p$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, $F$ is continuous on all of $N$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I assume that $F$ is differentiable, then it follows that it is continuous as you showed. But isn't the hypothesis being used to make sense of the definition? So, before even using it, in order for it to make sense (and $F(U) \subset V$), don't we need continuity?

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense to break Tu's statement into two parts. The first part is the definition of smoothness for a map between smooth manifolds. His last sentence is a proposition, saying "Any smooth map $F \colon N \to M$ is continuous. For such a map, we can choose the chart neighborhoods so $F(U) \subset V$." In particular, notice my proof above proves the first sentence of this proposition, and does not use the second sentence.